# How can I create a table as displayed in the below screen shot

Tags: html, css

Please help me on how can I create a table as mentioned in the below screen shot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgf2Z.png

Thank you in advance!!

```html
<table border=1px solid; style="border-collapse:collapse;" RULES=COLS>
  <tr>
    <th>Duration </th>
    <th style="text-align:left;">Topic</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>10 min </td>
    <td> Recap of FY17 CSP Incentives </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 20 min </td>
    <td> Partner Incentive Experience Onboarding </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 15 min </td>
    <td> Updating Banking Details/Partner Requirements </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 10 min </td>
    <td> Understanding MPN IDs </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 5 min </td>
    <td> Q&A and Closing Session Survey </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: where is the code?

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: Just add `th {
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
}` in your CSS

Comment: Thank you Nishanth!  Also I am new to the platform so sorry for pasting the code directly in comment section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following to css:

```
tr {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

th {
  border: 0;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

Here is the snippet:

```css
tr {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

th {
  border: 0;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table border=1px solid; style="border-collapse:collapse;" RULES=COLS>
  <tr>
    <th>Duration </th>
    <th>Topic</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>10 min </td>
    <td> Recap of FY17 CSP Incentives </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 20 min </td>
    <td> Partner Incentive Experience Onboarding </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 15 min </td>
    <td> Updating Banking Details/Partner Requirements </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 10 min </td>
    <td> Understanding MPN IDs </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 5 min </td>
    <td> Q&A and Closing Session Survey </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are unfamiliar with HTML, I would recommend you to use this website to generate HTML tables:

http://www.tablesgenerator.com/html_tables

Answer (score 0):

By Using Colspan property you can do this

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">COlumn</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Column A</td>
    <td>Column B</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code.

```
   <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <th>H1</th>
        <th>H2</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>R1</td>
        <td>R1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>R2</td>
        <td>R2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>R3</td>
        <td>R3</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

[Check demo here](http://codepen.io/inquisitive/pen/PpXWbz?editors=1111)